# Can anyone please help me understand SharedPreferences in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, cs50

I am building a pokedex app in which the app needs to remember the saved pokemons but the documentation for SharedPreferences is very confusing. How do i add that in PokemonActivity. I know that it needs to be added along with button for "Catch/Release" but how do i do that. Is it like a variable for like a function is what i am really confused about.

```js
PokemonActivity.java

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class PokemonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView nameTextView;
    private TextView numberTextView;
    private TextView type1TextView;
    private TextView type2TextView;
    private String url;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private Button button;
    ImageView imageView;
    private TextView pokemondesc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pokemon);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        nameTextView = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_name);
        numberTextView = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_number);
        type1TextView = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_type1);
        type2TextView = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_type2);
        button = findViewById(R.id.catchbutton);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_image);
        pokemondesc = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_desc);

        load();
    }

    public void load() {
        type1TextView.setText("");
        type2TextView.setText("");

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    pokemonid = response.getInt("id");
                    String url1 = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/" + pokemonid + "/";
                    final JsonObjectRequest requestdisc = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url1, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray flavorEntries = response.getJSONArray("flavor_text_entries");
                                for (int i = 0; i < flavorEntries.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject description = flavorEntries.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String lang = description.getJSONObject("language").getString("name");

                                    if(lang.equals("en")){
                                        String flavorText = description.getString("flavor_text");
                                        pokemondesc.setText(flavorText);
                                        break;
                                    }

                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e("cs50", "Json error", e);
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("cs50", "flavorText list error", error);
                        }
                    });
                    requestQueue.add(requestdisc);

                    nameTextView.setText(response.getString("name"));
                    numberTextView.setText(String.format("#%03d", response.getInt("id")));

                    String imgUrl = response.getJSONObject("sprites").getString("front_default");
                    new DownloadSpriteTask().execute(imgUrl);

                    JSONArray typeEntries = response.getJSONArray("types");
                    for (int i = 0; i < typeEntries.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject typeEntry = typeEntries.getJSONObject(i);
                        int slot = typeEntry.getInt("slot");
                        String type = typeEntry.getJSONObject("type").getString("name");

                        if (slot == 1) {
                            type1TextView.setText(type);
                        }
                        else if (slot == 2) {
                            type2TextView.setText(type);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("cs50", "Pokemon json error", e);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("cs50", "Pokemon details error", error);
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
    public boolean pokemonIsCaught = false;
    public void toggleCatch(View view) {
        // gotta catch 'em all!
        if (!pokemonIsCaught) {
            pokemonIsCaught = true;
            button.setText("Release");
        } else {
            pokemonIsCaught = false;
            button.setText("Catch");
        }
    }
    private class DownloadSpriteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("cs50", "Download sprite error", e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            // load the bitmap into the ImageView!
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
    }
    public static int pokemonid = 0;
}
```

EDIT 1:
I Changed my code to add that SharedPreferences part like this but it does not seem to work, can anyone please help me point out the issue here.

```js
package edu.harvard.cs50.pokedex;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class PokemonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView nameTextView;
    private TextView numberTextView;
    private TextView type1TextView;
    private TextView type2TextView;
    private String url;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private Button button;
    ImageView imageView;
    private TextView pokemondesc;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String savedpok = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pokemon);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        nameTextView = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_name);
        numberTextView = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_number);
        type1TextView = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_type1);
        type2TextView = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_type2);
        button = findViewById(R.id.catchbutton);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_image);
        pokemondesc = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_desc);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(savedpok,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        load();
    }

    public void load() {
        type1TextView.setText("");
        type2TextView.setText("");

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    pokemonid = response.getInt("id");
                    String url1 = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/" + pokemonid + "/";
                    final JsonObjectRequest requestdisc = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url1, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray flavorEntries = response.getJSONArray("flavor_text_entries");
                                for (int i = 0; i < flavorEntries.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject description = flavorEntries.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String lang = description.getJSONObject("language").getString("name");

                                    if(lang.equals("en")){
                                        String flavorText = description.getString("flavor_text");
                                        pokemondesc.setText(flavorText);
                                        break;
                                    }

                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e("cs50", "Json error", e);
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("cs50", "flavorText list error", error);
                        }
                    });
                    requestQueue.add(requestdisc);

                    nameTextView.setText(response.getString("name"));
                    numberTextView.setText(String.format("#%03d", response.getInt("id")));

                    String imgUrl = response.getJSONObject("sprites").getString("front_default");
                    new DownloadSpriteTask().execute(imgUrl);

                    JSONArray typeEntries = response.getJSONArray("types");
                    for (int i = 0; i < typeEntries.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject typeEntry = typeEntries.getJSONObject(i);
                        int slot = typeEntry.getInt("slot");
                        String type = typeEntry.getJSONObject("type").getString("name");

                        if (slot == 1) {
                            type1TextView.setText(type);
                        }
                        else if (slot == 2) {
                            type2TextView.setText(type);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("cs50", "Pokemon json error", e);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("cs50", "Pokemon details error", error);
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
    public boolean pokemonCaught = false;
    public void toggleCatch(View view) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        String name = nameTextView.getText().toString();

        // gotta catch 'em all!
        if (!pokemonCaught) {
            editor.putString(name, name);
            editor.apply();
            editor.commit();
            pokemonCaught = true;
            button.setText("Release");
        } else {
            editor.remove(name);
            editor.apply();
            editor.commit();
            pokemonCaught = false;
            button.setText("Catch");
        }
    }
    private class DownloadSpriteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("cs50", "Download sprite error", e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            // load the bitmap into the ImageView!
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
    }
    public static int pokemonid = 0;

    
}
```

Comment: How you want to save pokemons in string, boolean or both..?

Comment: boolean values.

Comment: i know its confusing just because i made a class and only call static functions and pas valuse. its very help full

Answer (score 0):

If you are confusing in shared preference you can include my gist in your project and call your desired function its help you

[Click here and get Shared Preference File In Java](https://gist.github.com/RanaUmer1/0fda66a1be9c6f07b00d40fda8cf8073)

In your case

Save value

```
AppPreference.saveData(this, true, "KEY")
```

Get value

```
AppPreference.getSavedData(this, "KEY")
```

Comment: I tried by doing this but it didnt work too, any other ay for this to work

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code that can help you get started with SharedPreferences. You can make it your base structure to develop on it further.

```
private SharedPreferences mPref;
private static final String SETTINGS_NAME = "default_settings";


//Initiate the shared pref
// Here, SETTINGS_NAME is a name for your shared pref
mPref = context.getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Once you have initiated your shared pref, you can get the data like this:

```
//Here FieldName is a name for your data, in this case can be pokemon name
//If there is no data with the FieldName, the default value will be returned.
mPref.getString("FieldName", "DefaultValue");
mPref.getBoolean("AnotherFieldName", false);
```

To set a data, use this code:

```
//We use the Editor class of shared pref to add data
private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
mEditor = mPref.edit();
mEditor.putString("FieldName", YOUR_VALUE);
mEditor.putBoolean("AnotherFieldName", BOOLEAN_VALUE);
mEditor.commit();
```

Read more at : [Android Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

Comment: how do i do it for boolean values

Comment: Updated the answer with boolean task

Comment: 1. You have shared pref name as empty (savedPok variable). 2. editor.putString(name, name); Use a hardcoded string or a variable string ith fixed name)

Answer (score 0):

Well in your case, change the code in toogleCatch method to be like this:

public void toggleCatch(View view) {

```
    SharedPreferences pokemonPrefs = getSharedPreferences("pokemon", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pokemonPrefs.edit();

    String name = nameTextView.getText().toString();

    // gotta catch 'em all!
    if (!pokemonCaught) {
        editor.putString("pokemon_name", name);
        pokemonCaught = true;
        button.setText("Release");
    } else {
        editor.putString("pokemon_name", "empty");
        pokemonCaught = false;
        button.setText("Catch");
    }
    editor.apply();
```

}

Then call this when you want to get the pokemon name:

SharedPreferences pokemonPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("pokemon", 0);

String pokemonName = pokemonPrefs.getString("pokemon_name", "empty");

Change the hardcoded strings to constant later after you understand it.